# Check function availability in Core Foundation

Tags: ios, core-foundation

I want to use a Core Foundation method that is only available on the latest iOS SDK, and fallback to a different one for previous SDKs. Is there something similar to Cocoa's way of doing it for NSObject?:

```
 - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

A bit more of context, let's say ABAddressBookCreate() would only be available in iOS5, and my app is targeting iOS 4.3+. I would want to check if ABAddressBookCreate() is available at runtime and perform different actions depending on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (doesn't need weak linking):

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation", RTLD_NOW);
void *createFunc = dlsym(handle, "ABAddressBookCreate");

if (createFunc != NULL)
{
    // available
    ABAddressBookRef (*_ABAddressBookCreate)(void) = createFunc;
    // then use this function pointer as normally
}
```

If you can provide weak linking:

```
if (ABAddressBookCreate != NULL)
{
   // available
}
```

Comment: Why are you running `dlopen()`, etc?  You should be able to just use `if (ABAddressBookCreate != NULL)`, as explained in the link that @Darren supplied. As long as your base/target SDKs are set correctly, that should work.

Comment: @ConradShultz no other option if you can't weak link.

Comment: Ah, I missed your note up top about that.  But on all reasonably modern iOS and OS X releases, weak linking is supported and encouraged, no?

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried it, but maybe this is helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

Check listing 3-2.